# How to get NSManagedObject ObjectID (objectID.isTemporaryID==NO) after insert to FetchResultsController?

Tags: core-data

I am using CoreData and i want to get an objectID (not temporary) after insert/saved the new NSManagedObject into context.

In my presenting vc save:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
EventMO *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EventMO" inManagedObjectContext:context];            
if ([context save:&error]) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In my main view controller using fetchResultViewController with a tableView, where can i get the new saved NSmanagedObject objectID, that is `objectID.isTemporaryID==NO`

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
}
```

I tried  `[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:newPath];` after `[[self tableView] endUpdates];` but seems not work. The error:

```
po [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:_insertedIndexPath]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Also i am not sure after endUpdates isTemporaryID is NO.

**EDIT**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
...
   EventMO *event   = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (!event.objectID.isTemporaryID) {
        Event *e = [Event new];
        e.eventID = event.objectID;
    }else{
      //It will get into this even after "save" method. Why?
      NSLog(@"This is temporary id");
    }
   ...
}
```

---

I guess here(after endupdates) should not be temporary id, i want to check it by:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
        [[self tableView] endUpdates];
EventMO *event   = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//po this event, get the error below
    }
```

i got the error.

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

**EDIT 2**
I have both classes below:

```
@interface Event : NSObject
@interface EventMO : NSManagedObject
```

My UITableViewCell subclass only has a property event:

```
@interface CountCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) Event *event;
@end
```

My tableView depends on if user registered or not. If registered `Event` should be used, or `EventMO` should be used for locally by core data. So after a new `EventMO` was created and saved, i need `CountCell` to display it. So i have to convert from `EventMO` to `Event` to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you save, you get a persistent object ID... unless you are not connected directly to a PSC, and have a parent MOC instead.

Basically, you only get a persistent object ID when saving from a MOC directly connected to a PSC.

However, you can convert into a persistent object ID anytime you want with the `NSManagedObjectContext` method

```
- (BOOL)obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:(NSArray *)objects
                               error:(NSError **)error;
```

**Edit**

First, if your code depends on knowing if an object ID is temporary or not, you should rethink you logic... this does not sound right, unless you are writing some special core data code.

Second, if your MOC has a PSC and not a parent MOC, you must be querying the objectID and it's temp/perm status before the context is saved.  Why don't you do something like this where you save the context...

```
NSLog(@"before save: %@", [moc registeredObjects]);
BOOL result = [moc save:&error];
NSLog(@"after save: %@", [moc registeredObjects]);
```

and you will see the IDs of all objects... you can visually distinguish between the ones that are temporary and the ones that are permanent.

The temporary ones look like this...

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7f8834836e10> (
  entity: Foo;
  id: 0x7f8834836e70 <x-coredata:///Foo/tECDD46E2-3D01-4E5D-BCE8-1DD8DB2138A512>;
  data: { identifier = 8; }),
```

The permanent ones look like this...

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7f8834836e10> (
  entity: Foo;
  id: 0x7f8834c231e0 <x-coredata://38B5921E-4638-42FD-AD94-78555561DBA7/Foo/p2>;
  data: { identifier = 8; }),
```

After the save, all objects should have permanent IDs.

Remember, the FRC will get updates anytime the MOC changes, and not just when a save occurs.

The exception you reference at the end of your question looks like a bad indexPath.

Comment: What does that mean " not connected directly to a PSC"? I have a [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator]; only on AppDelegate.m, and use only one managedObjectContext which belongs to AppDelegate.m too. After [context save:&error], my tableview cellforrow i checked the nsmangedobject instance, it's temporary. thanks!

Comment: That's connected to a PSC.  You will get a permanent ID after saving to PSC.  Please post some code demonstrating what you are seeing.

Comment: I edited my question. And actually if i use obtainPermanentIDsForObjects method, it works well. But i am just wondering why after save still not a permanent id.

Comment: Can you check my new edit why i use it? I am wonder if my logic is correct, thanks! Any way you provide a great help! thanks!